# Recyclerview's notifyDataSetChanged does not take effect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

My code is like below

```
 RecyclerViewAdapter violateRuleListAdapter;
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
 ...
   myDataset=getFromDatabase();     
   violateRuleListAdapter = new ViolateRuleListAdapter(mContext, myDataset);
   mViolateRuleRecyclerView.setAdapter(violateRuleListAdapter);
 }
 @Override
 public void onResume() {
    myDataset=getFromDatabase();   
    violateRuleListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

The app get dataset from db which changes in other activity.But when I get back,I find the adapter has not changed.Can't I use it like BaseAdapter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `getFromDatabase();` returns new object so the original reference that passed in to the `recyclerview` is lost and dose not change. what you need to do is changing the content of `myDataset` instead of the reference of it for example if `myDataset` is a list use below code:

```
 myDataset.clear();
 myDataset.addAll(getFromDatabase());
```

Comment: Thank you!It's right.But maybe it will cause a problem of efficiency.